# Task with/wihout async and await

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have this method :

```
public static Task TaskMethod ()
{
    Task.Delay(30000); 
    return Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("From Task") ); 
}
```

If I call it like this:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before calling the task");
    TaskMethod();
    Console.WriteLine("after calling the task"); 
    Console.ReadLine(); 
}
```

I have this output:

> before calling the task
> after calling the task
> From Task

But if I call this:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before calling the task");
    await TaskMethod();
    Console.WriteLine("after calling the task"); 
    Console.ReadLine(); 
}
```

I have this result:

> before calling the task
> From Task
> after calling the task

Is this behavior normal? Why I'm allowed to await the task without using async?
What I'm missing?

Comment: Note that `Task.Delay` is doing nothing in your code.

Comment: You `await` a `Task` and that is what `TaskMethod` returns.

Comment: Re your actual question: `async` is a modifier that allows `await` to be used _within_ the method that the modifier is applied to. It's `Task` that allows you to await a method, regardless of it having the `async` modifier. Hopefully somebody can explain that more eloquently than I can.

Comment: All `await` needs is a running `Task` or other awaitable. It neither knows nor cares *how* you created such a thing.

Comment: @Llama if i call 'TaskMethod' without awaiting it , does it run asynchronously ?

Comment: "if i call 'TaskMethod' without awaiting it , does it run asynchronously ? " actually then it runs synchronously ;) sounds weird and confusing, but Visual Studio will tell it to you and underline it with a green survy line

Comment: @MongZhu how is that possible ? , the output shows that "Console.WriteLine("after calling the task"); " get executed before the task finished  that very confusing

Comment: I am writing an explanation, give me a second

Comment: I'll leave Mong Zhu to the full explanation, but take a look at [this code](https://rextester.com/FAM65102), and then add `await` before `Task.Run`. You'll note that without, everything except "From task" runs on the main thread. When `await` is added, the method is suspended and everything that follows `Task.Run` is run on its own thread.

Comment: What is the intention of the line `Task.Delay(30000);`? Did you omitted the `await` at the beginning of the line intentionally or by mistake?

Comment: I don't think you are at the stage of asking a question, it seems you just need to do more reading. Any answer here will not fill in the gaps for you to understand this to level you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to explain.

Case: You don't await the returning value then it will execute the line and proceed to execute the next.

```
Console.WriteLine("before calling the task"); // execute 1
TaskMethod();                                 // execute 2
Console.WriteLine("after calling the task");  // execute 3
```

The confusing output that you get is because your machine needs less time to execute the 3rd command than it needs to execute the 2nd (creating a task, starting it, printint to console). The 2nd call runs in parallel to the 3rd. This is also due to the fact that the `Task.Delay` call is not waiting because you don't `await` it and the same principle applies there as it applies here.

To give you a little examplary proof here is a code that introduces a slight synchronous delay between the 2nd and 3rd call:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before calling the task");
    TaskMethod();
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    Console.WriteLine("after calling the task");
    //Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This gives the starting of the 2nd call a little more time to be executed before the 3rd step is performed. And you get the output:

> before calling the task
> From Task
> after calling the task

Now to the fact that the method `Main` runs actually synchronous on the main thread. This screenshot from LINQPad shows the message that Visual Studio would also display:

[image]

It tells you that the main method will block the main thread until it is finished. Because there is no await in it.

Whereas the `TaskMethod` inside the `Main` will run asynchronously and in parallel to the next commands which runs on the main thread! Whoever is faster gets to print it's message.

Why the `Task.Delay` call is useless without await ?=!

The `Delay` method returns a task which is started, actually quite exactly like your `TaskMethod`. If you don't await this delay task, it will run in parallel. Thus obliterating the entire effect of a delay. You should actually notice that your console prints all 3 lines at the same time, there is no delay between the second and third line!

> Why I'm allowed to await the task without using async?

Because the necessity of `async` refers always to the method inside which the `await` call is made and **not** the method that is awaited! This can be seen in the fact that you cannot simply add an await to the `Task.Delay` call because the `TaskMethod` is not declared as `async`!

[image]

(Hopefully) last EDIT:

The `await` operator needs a `Task` whose execution it can await, and because your `TaskMethod` returns a `Task` the operator can be applied.
You can make nice things with it if you take the returning task. You can then decide when to wait for the end of it's execution!:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before calling the task");
    Task taskToBeAwaitedMuchLater = TaskMethod();
    Console.WriteLine("after calling the task");
    await taskToBeAwaitedMuchLater;
    Console.WriteLine("after awaiting the result of the task");
    //Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

> before calling the task
> after calling the task
> From Task
> after awaiting the result of the task

Comment: "...is because the **compiler** needs less time to execute the 3rd..." shouldn't this be the runtime 

Comment: @BernoulliIT your're right, thx. changed it to "your machine" ;)

Comment: *"This delay is executed again on a different thread and if you don't await it, it will run in parallel."* Actually [no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) is needed to "execute" a `Task.Delay` task. If you create 1,000,000 `Task.Delay` tasks, you'll not see 1,000,000 threads in the Windows Task Manager.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thank you for the cherry picking. Please feel free to edit my post and correct the unprecise wording :)

Comment: Mong Zhu life is too short to correct semantic mistakes in other peoples' posts. I am willing to correct spelling mistakes, but that's about it. 